# Selenium Select Multiple options from dropdown

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver

I have to select multiple values from dropdown [Some Values are hidden, till I scroll down]. I can select multiple options but I think there must be better way of selecting more than one values from dropdown.

1. I’m using parameterization to pass the value, I would like to select.
2. If the dropdown isMultiple, I’m going thru for loop to find all options till it find the parameterization value.
3. I’m calling this method on my test cases
4. test.selectMulti(“foo”);
5. test.selectMulti(“fooz”);
6. I’m able to select both options but I don’t think this is the most optimize way of doing it.

Does anyone knows better way to pass multiple values part of parametrization and select once options are found. Keep in mind some time I might have to select one option, sometime two and sometime more options.

```
public void selectMulti (String list) {

    WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));
    Select select = new Select(list);

    if (select.isMultiple()) {

        try {
            List<WebElement> optionLists = select.getOptions();
            listFound = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < optionLists.size(); i++) {
                String text = optionLists.get(i).getText();
                if (text.equals(list)) {
                    optionLists.get(i).click();
                    listFound = true; break;
        }
            } if (listFound) {
    Log.pass();
            } else {
    Log.failed();
            }
        }  catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    } else {
    Log.failed();
    }

    }
```

Comment: You've got several issues I see off the bat. 1. The first line of code redefines `list` as a `WebElement` which hammers over the `String list` you passed into the function. 2. The `String list` you pass in should be `String[] list` (an array of `String`) to handle the case where you want to select multiple items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something more like this. It solves the issues I mentioned in my comment and also cleans up the code a bit and adds some additional error cases. Since the dropdown is a `SELECT`, you can use the [`Select`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) related methods, one of which is `selectByVisibleText()` so you shouldn't have to loop through the `OPTIONS` and click them.

```
public void selectMulti(String[] listItems)
{
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("abc")));

    if (listItems.length > 1 && !select.isMultiple())
    {
        Log.fail("The SELECT is not a multiple select but the list provided is larger than 1.");
        return;
    }

    for (String listItem : listItems)
    {
        try
        {
            select.selectByVisibleText(listItem);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            Log.failed(listItem + " was not an available option");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.